# SQL SERVER 2008 r2 - ERRO TEMPDB

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Bom dia, por acaso alguém sabe uma solução para este erro :

```
Msg 8921, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Check terminated. A failure was detected while collecting facts. Possibly tempdb out of space or a system table is inconsistent. Check previous errors.
```

Da maneira que o banco esta, consegue se fazer consulta mas quando tento rodar algum processo de correção do banco ele retorna este erro, O banco possui 24gb.

Comment: Qual a operação você está tentando realizar e que gera esse erro? Adicione essa informação na pergunta para que fique mais claro.

Comment: No caso o banco de dados funciona com um aplicativo comercial e não esta sendo acessível devido ao erro. Quando tento reparar no sql ele retorna o erro impedindo corrigir.

Answer (score 3):

Neste caso tem três coisas a se fazer:

1. Verifique o espaço em disco onde o tempdb está. Como o checkdb usa o mesmo para armazenar os dados de verificação temporariamente, provavelmente ele não tem mais espaço para poder crescer. Verifique também se os dois arquivos do tempdb estão configurados para não ter limitação de tamanho.
2. Se a situação acima não for a causa, você provavelmente vai ter que fazer o seguinte:

   - Executa esse comando no banco de dados, ele vai estimar o espaço necessário para poder executar o checkdb: Dbcc checkalloc('issuedb') with estimateonly;
   - Se ainda der erro o comando acima, tenta restaurar este banco de dados (sem dar detach nem nada, pelo amor de Deus) em um outro server, baseado em uma mídia de backup mais recente. Ai tenta fazer a verificação novamente.
3. Se nada do acima resolver, tente criar um outro banco de dados copiando os dados deste, ou verifica com dbcc checktable('tabela') em cada uma delas pra ver qual está com problema.

Está mensagem, pelas pesquisas que eu fiz, vem acompanhada de mais informações. Tem como postar a mensagem completa do erro (com as mensagens subsequentes), e também o comando executado por você. Também li que este tipo de erro, quando é relacionado a tabelas de sistema, são erros dificilmente recuperáveis, por isso ao rodas os comandos, vai editando sua pergunta com os resultados.

P.S: Caso não dê jeito mesmo, tente usar o [Migration Wizard](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard) do SQL Server mesmo para poder migrar as informações para um novo banco de dados, ou utilize a ferramenta open-source [SQL Database Migration Wizard](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) para poder migrar os dados para um novo banco de dados.

Comment: Vou fazer o procedimento que você informou, e retorno com as informações obtidas , obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Fiz os procedimentos que você me passou mas realmente não funcionou , o banco pelo jeito não tem muito o que fazer. Não sei se é permitido aqui no fórum mas você teria um passo a passo de como eu posso migrar os dados do banco corrompido para um outro com a estrutura sem erros?

Comment: @Wêklef dá uma olhada [nesse docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/use-the-copy-database-wizard) da Microsoft, que ele explica como usar a wizard do próprio SQL. Ou usa [esta ferramenta](https://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/), que também ela faz rapidinho. Editei a resposta com as duas soluções.